# Entity Framework Core assigning null value to non-null primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Update: I have fixed the problem. The solution in my case was missing from my migration and will be specific to your database manager.

The fix is this line in the migration:

```
Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
  .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn)
```

I have a table that I am trying to let EF handle the id generation. The Id is a long.

The model looks like:

```
public virtual long Id { get; set; }    
public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

The migration looks like:

```
migrationBuilder
    .CreateTable("MyEntity",
        table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
            Created = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
        }
```

The model snapshot looks like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("MyEntity", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<long>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                    b.Property<DateTime>("Created");
                    b.HasKey("Id");
                }
```

When creating a new entity and not setting the Id, the Id has the default value of 0. When inserting that value into `dataContext.MyEntities.Add(newEntity)` and inspecting the entity it now has an extremely large negative value (seems to be negative long.MaxValue). The problem is that sometime during the `dataContext.SaveChanges();` EF seems to convert this negative value into null and throws.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyEntity" (
    "Id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "Created" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: can you post the generated table design/schema

Comment: The implementation differs per database provider. Which one is this?

Comment: This is for postgres, using "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.1.0",
    "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design": "1.1.0"

Comment: Yeah... you'll have to find out how they implement it.

Comment: I edited and added my schema. It was my understanding that EF handled the Id generation?

Comment: Look at the red text blocks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add

Comment: Thank you for that link, it's too bad this situation isn't handled by default.

Comment: This pattern requires highly specialized scripts that exploit provider-specific features. EF can't take care of all that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("Id");
```

or adding the Key decorator (Data Annotations):

```
[Key]
public virtual long Id { get; set; }
```

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/columns

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I have updated my model snapshot in the post to reflect that, it was setting the key property as Id but is still setting it to null.